# Sort Array By Count of Values

Tags: php, sorting

I will use my specific example to explain:

My array consists of values that represent the most specific category that a product belongs to, however it may belong to different branches on a category tree each branch is then represented by an array value which is itself an array of all of the parent categories that the category belongs to.

I would like to find the longest branch E.g the category that a product belongs to which has the largest number of parent categories. for example:

```
var_dump($my_breadcrumbs);
array(
  [0] => array( [0] => Object Category , [1] Object Category) 
  [1] => array( [0] => Object Category , [1] Object Category, [2] Object Category)
```

I want to move the array element with the largest number of values to position 0

I can do this through a series of tests but I want to see if there is a way to use php's sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
usort($my_breadcrumbs, function ($a, $b){
    return  count($b) - count($a);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need to sort just to get the longest one; [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/array_reduce) can act like `max` with a key:

```
$longest = array_reduce($my_breadcrumbs, function($a, $b) {
    return count($b) > count($a) ? $b : $a;
});
```

Comment: I wish I could checkmark the both of you because both work for my very specific example however I think that being that the title's first word is sort Pe de Leao is more appropriate. I just wanted to give props to you as well.